# Quiero regresar al input para volver a preguntarle al usuario

Tags: python

soy nuevo en python, apenas estoy empezando mis clases y me quiero adelantar un poco investigando y eso.
Quiero regresar a preguntarle al usuario si ninguna de las condiciones del if o alif se cumplen y lo llevan a else en donde informa de error, además de que me informa de error, quiero que le vuelva a preguntar al usuario **X =  input('Responda: Verdadero o Falso: ')**

```
print(" ")
print("a- Un programa es una lista bien definida, ordenada y finita de operaciones que permite hallar la solución a un problema." )
print(" ")

X =  input('Responda: Verdadero o Falso: ')

if X == "Falso":
    print(" ")
    print ('Respuesta correcta')
elif X == "Verdadero":
    print(" ") 
    print("Respuesta incorrecta")
else:
    print(" ") 
    print("ERROR. Recuerda que sólo puedes ingresar Verdadero o Falso")
```

Agradeceria que me enseñaran como hacerlo junto con la explicación.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

amigo para hacer eso tienes que aprender a manejar bucles te dejo un [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQGhU1526Oo&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BlvPxziopYZRd55pdqFwkeS&index=14)

bueno para hacer esto usaremos un bucle while True osea sera un bucle infinito hasta que la condicion sea falsa o hasta que se rompa con la funcion break

cada ves que el usuario ingrese un dato incorrecto el bucle se volvera a ejecutar entonces si el usuario ingresa verdadero o falso el bucle se rompe.

```
print("a- Un programa es una lista bien definida, ordenada y finita de 
operaciones que permite hallar la solución a un problema." )


while True:
    X =  input('Responda: Verdadero o Falso: ')

    if X == "Falso":
       print(" \nRespuesta correcta")
       break
    elif X == "Verdadero":
        print(" \nRespuesta incorrecta")
        break
    else:
        print(" \nERROR. Recuerda que sólo puedes ingresar Verdadero o Falso")
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias !

Comment: si te sirvió mi respuesta no olvides marcarla

Comment: Segun yo, ya la marque.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto te funcione:

```
print("\na- Un programa es una lista bien definida, ordenada y finita de operaciones que permite hallar la solución a un problema.\n" )

X =  input('Responda: Verdadero o Falso: ')
while True:
    if X == "Falso":
        print ('\nRespuesta correcta')
        break
    elif X == "Verdadero":
        print("\nRespuesta incorrecta")
        break
    else:
        print("\nERROR. Recuerda que sólo puedes ingresar Verdadero o Falso")
        X =  input('Responda: Verdadero o Falso: ')
```

El objetivo del ciclo es que luego de mostrar el error y solicitar nuevamente la respuesta del usuario, se pueda mostrar si es correcta o no la respuesta o, si existe otro error, volver a proceder con lo explicado anteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

Como todavía no sabes sobre los bucles ya se cual es el error, la solucion es que cuando tu escribes verdadero o falso después le das a espacio o haces espacio antes y eso hace que te de error